# Error about a void function with a vector argument

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, void

I'm having a coding problem about a "simple" exercise about sorting what's inside a vector of n integers number. The problem is that the compiler doesnt accept void as a type for the function sort (And it must be a void function). But I do't really understand why. For the variables the type matches (pointer <-> v.begin() for example) but for the fucntion it does not. Any help appreciated! Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Vit;


void sort( Vit begin, Vit end){
    int len = end - begin;
    for(begin; begin < end; ++begin){
        for( int i = 1; i < len; ++i){
            if(*begin < *(begin +i ) ){
                *begin = *(begin + i);
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<< "* ";
    for( begin; begin < end; ++begin){
        std::cout<< *begin<< " ";
    }
    std::cout<< "*";
    return;
}



int main(){
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    for(Vit it = v.begin();it != v.end(); ++it){
        std::cin >> *it;
    }

    void sort (v.begin() , v.end());

}
```

Comment: In main, change ` void sort (v.begin() , v.end());` to ` sort (v.begin() , v.end());`.

Comment: Correct! Thanks a lot it's a really stupid error...
Could you also explain me why the code doesn't work? It should sort the elements inside of a vector.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Nope. Ask a new question. But first look carefully at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors.
You are incrementing begin in the first for loop, but never resetting it. So the second for loop will never be entered. Each ++begin changes the position of your iterator! The loop for( int i = 1; i < len; ++i) will go to the current position of begin plus i and thus leave the memory.
The following should do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Vit;

void sort( Vit begin, Vit end){
  for(Vit pos1=begin; pos1 < end; ++pos1) {
    for(Vit pos2=pos1+1; pos2 < end; ++pos2) {
      if(*pos1 < *pos2 ) {
    int swap = *pos1;
    *pos1 = *pos2;
    *pos2 = swap;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout<< "* ";
  for(Vit it=begin; it < end; ++it){
    std::cout<< *it<< " ";
  }
  std::cout<< "*";
  return;
}

int main(){
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  for(Vit it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it){
    std::cin >> *it;
  }

  sort (v.begin() , v.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That portion of code on swapping was really useful. It didn't fullfilled the requests of the execrcise but I managed to understand what was missing and I've corrected the code, really thanks a lot!